# Is "The disk copy of 'filename.psd' was changed since..." dialog a sign of harddrive issues?

Tags: hard-drive, adobe-photoshop, dialog, macos

I saw this message and I'm not sure if it is a sign of harddrive issues (corruption, etc) or anything I should be concerned about. It popped up in Photoshop when saving. Might also be worth noting that it is a file in my Dropbox folder.

[image: dialog screenshot]

Comment: I had this happen no more than ten minutes ago on Photoshop CS3, with a file not in Dropbox, and my SSD has passed all recent tests. It's probably nothing to be concerned about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely it's Dropbox. It could be that it synced to another machine, which added some metadata to it automatically, then synced back to your machine, so it looks to Photoshop as if it's changed, when only the file's metadata has. Unless this happens consistently with files outside of synced folders, it's probably nothing to worry about

Comment: No one else would have been editing the file but it is in a shared folder.

Comment: It could be that it synced to another machine, which added some metadata to it automatically, then synced back to your machine, so it looks to Photoshop as if it's changed, when only the file's metadata has. Unless this happens consistently with files outside of synced folders, it's probably nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Fusion 3 or 4 running with the Adobe Photoshop plugin active? I have been reading that the plugin does embed font sense metadata into the document, causing the error. If you do, you might want to try to turn off the plugin and see if you are still getting the error.